# Center A View using Java in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I center a View I created in Java? I have the following code in the onCreate method of an Activity:

```
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(5);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        gridLayout.addView(imageView, i);
    }
    setContentView(gridLayout);
```

Now, I'd like for the GridLayout containing the ImageViews to be vertically centered on the screen when the program runs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

set layout params for gridview and imageviews. 
You will be able to check the views clearly.